# Java code in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jsoup

I am running a map only job in Hadoop. The data-set is a set of html pages in a single file (returned by a crawler)

The mapper code is written in Java. I am using JSoup to parse. What I want as my output is a key that has both the contents of the title tag and the content of a meta tag. Ideally I should get 1592 records for my map output records. I am getting 3184.

The concatenation I attempt to do with this line of code is not happening.

```
       String MN_Job = (jobT + "\t" + jobsDetail);
```

What I get instead is each of these separately, hence double the number of outputs. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class JobsDataMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text keytext = new Text();
    private Text valuetext = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
        Elements desc = doc.select("head title, meta[name=twitter:description]");

        for (Element jobhtml : desc) {
            Elements title = jobhtml.select("title");
            String jobT = "";
            for (Element titlehtml : title) {
                jobT = titlehtml.text();
            }

            Elements meta  = jobhtml.select("meta[name=twitter:description]"); 
            String jobsDetail ="";

            for (Element metahtml : meta) {
                String content = metahtml.attr("content");
                String content1 = content.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " ");
                jobsDetail = content1.replaceAll(" (?i)a | (?i)able | (?i)about | (?i)across | (?i)after | (?i)all | (?i)almost | (?i)also | (?i)am | (?i)among | (?i)an | (?i)and | (?i)any | (?i)are | (?i)as | (?i)at | (?i)be | (?i)because | (?i)been | (?i)but | (?i)by | (?i)can | (?i)cannot | (?i)could | (?i)dear | (?i)did | (?i)do | (?i)does | (?i)either | (?i)else | (?i)ever | (?i)every | (?i)for | (?i)from | (?i)get | (?i)got | (?i)had | (?i)has | (?i)have | (?i)he | (?i)her | (?i)hers | (?i)him | (?i)his | (?i)how | (?i)however | (?i)i | (?i)if | (?i)in | (?i)into | (?i)is | (?i)it | (?i)its | (?i)just | (?i)least | (?i)let | (?i)like | (?i)likely | (?i)may | (?i)me | (?i)might | (?i)most | (?i)must | (?i)my | (?i)neither | (?i)no | (?i)nor | (?i)not | (?i)nbsp | (?i)of | (?i)off | (?i)often | (?i)on | (?i)only | (?i)or | (?i)other | (?i)our | (?i)own | (?i)rather | (?i)said | (?i)say | (?i)says | (?i)she | (?i)should | (?i)since | (?i)so | (?i)some | (?i)than | (?i)that | (?i)the | (?i)their | (?i)them | (?i)then | (?i)there | (?i)these | (?i)they | (?i)this | (?i)tis | (?i)to | (?i)too | (?i)twas | (?i)us | (?i)wants | (?i)was | (?i)we | (?i)were | (?i)what | (?i)when | (?i)where | (?i)which | (?i)while | (?i)who | (?i)whom | (?i)why | (?i)will | (?i)with | (?i)would | (?i)yet | (?i)you | (?i)your "," ");
            }

            String IT_Job = (jobT + "\t" + jobsDetail);

            keytext.set(IT_Job) ;
            valuetext.set("JobDetail");
            context.write( keytext, valuetext );        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know you should get 1592 records? I am unable to get any context from your question. Can you give us the link to the web page your web crawler extracts. That might help a little.

Comment: My crawler was set to visit 1592 pages and save the html source to a single file one after the other. I have checked for number of pages in the file using checks for number of title tags, html tags.

Comment: If you are using a `Unix` based system, maybe you can use something like `grep -c '<title>' filename` to get the number of times the title tag occurs in the file. If it matches 1592, then we can proceed from there.

Comment: it does match. I have that confirmed.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide that file here, so that one can debug the code?

Comment: It is pretty large file.

Comment: No the file that was generated by your crawler. Is it too big to be uploaded on the cloud somewhere?

Comment: how can I share a sample here (like two of the html sources on a file)?

Comment: is there a mail id i can send it to?

Comment: I can only see the linkedin page, no email id

Comment: Could you add the first few lines of the output file to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes to the original code removing the loops that were not necessary. What was happening the older code was that when there is a title in the record, it is output, and later when there is a content, it is output as well.  So, there are two writes per HTML file.

```
        public class JobsDataMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text keytext = new Text();
        private Text valuetext = new Text();
        private String jobT = new String();
        private String jobName= new String();

         @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {



 String line = value.toString();

 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
 Elements desc = doc.select("head title, meta[name=twitter:description]");

 for (Element jobhtml : desc){
 Elements title = jobhtml.select("title");


 String jobTT = title.text();
 jobT =jobTT ;

 if (jobT.length()> 0){

 jobName=jobTT;
 }

 Elements meta = jobhtml.select("meta[name=twitter:description]");
 String jobsDetail ="";

 String content = meta.attr("content");

 String content1 = content.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " ");
 jobsDetail = content1.toLowerCase();
 jobsDetail = content1.replaceAll(" a| able | about | across | after | all | almost | also | am | among | an | and | any | are | as | at | be| because | been | but | by | can | cannot | could | dear | did | do | does | either | else | ever | every | for | from | get | got | had | has | have | he | her | hers | him | his | how | however | i | if | in | into | is | it | its | just | least | let | like | likely | may | me | might | most | must | my | neither | no | nor | not | nbsp | of | off | often | on | only | or | other | our | own | rather | said | say | says | she | should | since | so | some | than | that | the | their | them | then | there | these | they | this | tis | to | too | twas | us | wants | was | we | were | what | when | where | which | while | who | whom | why | will | with | would | yet | you | your "," ");




     if (jobsDetail.length()>0) {

String MN_Job = (jobName+ "\t" + jobsDetail);

keytext.set(MN_Job) ;
valuetext.set("JobInIT");
context.write( keytext, valuetext );

 }

 }

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I know what the problem is. But the thing is that the solution might not be obvious in MapReduce. You might have to write your custom `RecordReader`. Let me explain the problem.

In your code you read line by line. Then you apply this to the line you read:

```
Elements desc = doc.select("head title, meta[name=twitter:description]");
```

But evidently, it might only have a `title` or a `<meta name=twitter:description>` tag. So you read one of those and store it. The other one remains blank. So at a time, only one of your variables, `jobT` and `jobsDetail` has any data. So for the code snippet:

```
String IT_Job = (jobT + "\t" + jobsDetail);
```

one time, the first one is blank and the second time, the other one is blank. So if you are expecting `n` records, you get `2n` records. Similarly, if you'll attempt to extract three fields, then you should get `3n` records. So you can test this theory by extracting another field and then checking if you are getting thrice the number of expected records.

If the theory turns out to be correct, you might want to delimit the webpages you extract with a specific delimiter string. Then you want to write a custom `RecordReader` which will read one html file at a time according to the delimiter and then process the entire html file at once. That way you'll get the `title` and the `meta` tags together.

Comment: Stripping the loops does not appear to help

Comment: Thanks for inputs Expressions_Galore. The construct that you mentioned was what was causing the error. I solved it using a workaround in the code. I am adding it as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could upvote the answer if you feel it was helpful :)

Comment: I tried but I do not have the necessary 15 points to upvote. Sorry abt that

Answer (score 0):

Just by the look at the numbers: `3184/2 = 1592`.

I think that your file is just duplicated in the input folder. I can't tell for sure, because you have not given the code how you submit the job, but maybe you can verify it with a simple:

```
 bin/hadoop fs -ls /your/input_path
```

When submitting, either make sure that there is just the single file in there, or just reference the single file in your submission logic.